# Chromedriver not being added to github

Tags: git, selenium, github, selenium-chromedriver

**Steps to reproduce:**
- Create a new repo on github
- Clone repo on desktop
- Add chromedriver to the folder
- Open terminal and run the following command
- git add .
- git commit -m "Added chromedriver"
- git push
- Refresh github on the created repo

**Expected result:**
- You should see the chromedriver

**Actual result:**
- Chromedriver is not there

Because of this, whoever clones the repo has to manually add the chromedriver to the project.

Am I missing something?

Comment: what is in your .gitignore file?

Comment: There is no .gitignore file.
I created a repo from scratch, cloned the repo to my desktop, copy and pasted chromedriver to the repo and when I check for any changes, the chromedriver is not being picked up.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the file? using `git commit -m 'my notes' path/to/my/file.ext `